# Explode something from URL string

Tags: php, explode

I need the best solution to get "token" from the URL.

**Example of the URL (always the same structure):**

```
https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=123456789&token=qwerty1@
```

I want to get only **`qwerty1@`** from this URL.

Which option is the best, safe and the faster to do this?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `parse_url` to get the querystring, then `parse_str` to get the `token`.

```
parse_str(parse_url(
   'https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=123456789&token=qwerty1@',
   PHP_URL_QUERY
), $result);

echo $result['token']; // qwerty1@
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
$arr = explode("=", $string);
echo end($arr); //prints "qwerty1@"
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not useful.  Please explain how this helps / answers the question.